# Parsing XML in swift fails with nil error

Tags: swift, xml, abort

I am attempting to parse an xml file using Swift. I have created a XMLParserDelegate class, `OSM`, which implements the following functions:

```
func parserDidStartDocument(_ parser: XMLParser)
func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser)
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:])
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
```

I use the delegate as follows:

```
let url = URL(string: "file:///Users/<Username>/Documents/Maps/OSMFiles/simple.osm")!
print(url.absoluteString)
let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: url)!
let osm = OSM()
parser.delegate = osm
print(parser.parse())
print(parser.parserError)
```

The code prints the following:

```
file:///Users/<Username>/Documents/Maps/OSMFiles/simple.osm
false
nil
```

Comment: But `nil` means there is no error? Did you run it in the debugger?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It would seem that way but the parser is returning false so it is failing in some way. I ran it in the debugger, there was no exception.

Comment: There are a couple of error handling methods in the delegate protocol you can implement (and I think you need to) so you can understand what goes wrong. Note that the parseError has a value after an "...operation abnormally terminates...", maybe this is a softer error like some kind of validation error.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for that, I have implemented the `parseErrorOccurred` and `validationErrorOccurred` functions but neither are called, are there other functions which can give more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the app sandboxing was the issue, possibly because I was trying to access a file outside the sandbox. Turning off sandboxing solves the issue.